# Java/Scala regex expression

Tags: java, regex, scala

I am a little unfamiliar with regex. I have a string along the following lines

```
val str20 = "unit/virtual-ExtractMe/domain-testing-ExtracMe-IgnoreMe"
```

The word I want to extract is "ExtractMe"(the first one that is seen above right before `domain-`. The format is of string is going to be same in the start but will change after the second slash and I need to ignore whatever is written after the second slash. My interest is to get whatever is written between `virtual-` and `second /` . In this case it is the first occurrence of the word ExtractMe. for example if I have this

```
val str20 = "unit/virtual-YouGotMe/domain-testing-ExtracMe-IgnoreMe"
```

The regex should get me the word "YouGotMe" as it is between `virtual- and the second forward slash`

Comment: I cannot help since I do not know what the problem with your approach is. Please share your attempt to see where it went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This `/virtual-(.*?)/` will get you all the matches in a group. You just have to get the first one. See : https://regex101.com/r/KX9VTt/2

In Scala regex, there is no need to escape the `/`, but if you are doing them in Java directly, you will need to escape them.

Comment: Agreed. Thumbs up!

Comment: @Seb The requirement is *between `virtual-` and the **second** forward slash*. The `^.*virtual-(.*)\/.*$` does not guarantee the `/` is the second one. The first `.*` will make the engine match the last occurrence of `virtual-` in the string, and then all up to the last `/` in the string. [Here is a case where it fails](https://regex101.com/r/KX9VTt/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, how do i enforce the second slash check?

Comment: I'll look into it.

Comment: @curiousengineer look at my edit. If you get the first group, it'll work with the second regex.

Comment: Note that you do not need to escape `/` in a Scala regex pattern. Regex delimiters are not used, and `/` is not a special regex metacharacter.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, you can use `findFirstMatchIn` to extract the first matched group as follows:

```
val pattern = """virtual-(.*?)/""".r

val str20 = "unit/virtual-ExtractMe/domain-testing-ExtracMe-IgnoreMe"

pattern.
  findFirstMatchIn(str20).
  map(_.group(1)).
  getOrElse("Error: No Match!!!")

res1: String = ExtractMe

val str20 = "unit/virtual-YouGotMe/domain-testing-ExtracMe-IgnoreMe"

pattern.
  findFirstMatchIn(str20).
  map(_.group(1)).
  getOrElse("Error: No Match!!!")

res2: String = YouGotMe
```